# Publish in apple store whith Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My error in publish Apple Store is **Code signing Alamofire.framework failed**
Can someone help me?

Comment: please show us the exact error, and describe how you have added Alamofire to your project

Comment: I added to podfile and error is Archive the file to Apple Store (Dsitribute App)